# .NET Service Repository Manager for SOA

Tags: .net, soa

I'm searching a .NET service repository manager that manages all web services and ws-* - like authorization , auditing and logging,support service transactions , ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of products that can apply runtime policies (e.g. security, auditing/logging), see http://www.soa.com/ for an example. Distributed transactions is rather more tricky as it requires that the backend systems have some way of supporting transactions or rolling back changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you mean but...
Is it something like Jenkins/Hudson you are looking for?
http://jenkins-ci.org/

/J